# reason: 'too many arguments: in Contract constructor', This is the last step before i deploy the contract, so any advice would be great

Tags: solidity, contract-development, openzeppelin, hardhat, binance-smart-chain

I got this error: Is there some error I have been making in the contract? Any help would I appreciate, if you need me to publish other contracts just tell me I will update this question with the contract add-in.

at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
reason: 'too many arguments:  in Contract constructor',
code: 'UNEXPECTED_ARGUMENT',
count: 1,
expectedCount: 0

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are giving a string argument -> “Hello, Hardhat” when you are deploying the contract but your contract does not expect any arguments.

So remove it and it should be ->

```
const nicola = await Nikola.deploy();
```

Answer (score 0):

you just use

> const nicola = await Nikola.deploy();